# Connecting computer to 2 different networks: VPN via WiFi, Ethernet for LAN

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vpn, lan

I couldn't find an answer online for this question:

Is it possible to connect the same computer to a VPN via WiFi, and at the same time through an Ethernet cable to my LAN ?

What I want to achieve is having an Apache or Tomcat (or any other server) establish a DB connection via the VPN, but be visible from the LAN.

To make it clear, I don't want to bridge networks, I don't want access to that DB from my LAN, just to "see" a server running on that computer.

The 2 adapters would get different IPs (Wifi would get 10.x.x.x, LAN would get 192.168.1.x), so the IPs won't clash.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is quite doable - You simply need to add a route out the WIFI's gateway for the VPN endpoint, and ensure that you don't have a default route out that Interface, and that the VPN only advertises the route to the server running the DB.

Once you have done that, everything should fit together seemlessly.

Comment: Thanks, but how exactly do I do that ? Keep in mind that I do NOT have admin rights on the machine.

Comment: Then you'll probably have to ask your administrator - changing IP route entries is not a user-level activity.